# "error: 'string' does not name a type" ao declarar strings

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, string

Segue o código

```
class Nome
{
    public:
        Nome(string nome, string sobreNome);
        void exibirNome();
        virtual ~Nome();
    protected:
    private:
         string nome;
         string sobreNome;
         
};
```

Erro

> error: expected ')' before 'nome'
>
> error: 'string' does not name a type
>
> error: 'string' does not name a type

Comment: Não tem mais nada no seu código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem que incluir o cabeçalho de `string`. E o nome completo do tipo seria `std::string`, então um `using` costuma ser apropriado para não ter que descrever o *namespace* todas as vezes. Em C++ o agrupamento dos nomes são separados do agrupamento dos códigos (arquivos *header*).

Dei uma reorganizada para evitar código redundante e ficar mais idiomático.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Nome {
        string nome;
        string sobreNome;
    public:
        Nome(string nome, string sobreNome);
        void exibirNome();
        virtual ~Nome(); //espero que vá usar, senão não tem porque criar isto
};
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Am7trS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Headercpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Header.cpp).

Comment: só faltava `using namespace std;`, deu certo valeu