# Diferença entre std::cout e cout?

Tags: c++, namespace, cout

Em C++ porque alguns usam `std::cout` e outros usam apenas `cout` é apenas o que o programador achar melhor?

Comment: Para utilizar apenas `cout` você precisa utilizar o namespace: `using namespace std;`. Os recursos da biblioteca padrão do C ++ são declarados dentro do espaço de nome `std`. Leia mais em [C++ Standard Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) e [Name visibility](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em C++ todos nomes definidos no **escopo global** pertencem a um **namespace**.

Um nome está no escopo global quando é declarado fora de uma função e de uma classe. Por exemplo

---

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 1;

int main()
{
    int b = 2;
    std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << "\n";
    {
       int c = 3;
       std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

No exemplo acima, a variável `a`está no escopo global (dizemos que é uma "variável global"), e as variáveis `b` e `c` estão em um **escopo local** (dizemos que são "variáveis locais"). A variável local `b` está no escopo da função `main`, e a variável local `c` está no escopo do **bloco** aberto pela chave `{` anterior, e fechado pela chave `}` que vem em seguida.

Pois bem, tudo isso foi para dizer que todos os nomes que estão no escopo global pertencem a um **namespace**. Um namespace, como o nome diz, é um "espaço de nomes", ou um "conjunto de nomes".

Quando um nome no escopo global não pertence explicitamente a um namespace, então automaticamente o nome pertence ao **namespace global**. Portanto, no exemplo acima, a variável global `a` pertence ao namespace global.

Para indicar que um nome no escopo global pertence a um namespace, precisamos dar o nome do namespace a que este nome pertence.

---

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 1;

namespace x
{
   int a = 2;
};

int main()
{
    int b = 3;
    std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << "\n";
    {
       int c = 3;
       std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "a=" << a << " x::a=" << x::a << "\n";
}
```

---

No exemplo acima temos duas variaveis `a` globais: uma que pertence ao namespace global (inicializada com 1) e uma que pertence ao namespace `x` (inicializada com 2).

Note que para referenciar a variável `a` que pertence ao namespace `x` precisamos fazer isso explicitamente, através da notação `x::a`.

Existem duas maneiras de simplificar a codificação e não ficar repetindo o nome do namespace. As duas maneiras se utilizam da **diretiva** `using`.

A primeira maneira simplifica a referência a apenas um nome do namespace. No exemplo acima, logo após declarar o `namespace x` utilizaríamos a diretiva `using x::a;`. Desta maneira, poderíamos referenciar a variável `x::a` apenas escrevendo `a`. Entretanto no exemplo acima isto não vai funcionar, pois vai criar conflito com a variável `a` (inicializada com 1) pertencente ao namespace global!

No exemplo seguinte a variável `x::y` é referenciada desta maneira simplificada.

---

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 1;

namespace x
{
   int a = 2;
   int y = 2;
};
using x::y;

int main()
{
    int b = 3;
    std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << "\n";
    {
       int c = 3;
       std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "a=" << a << " x::a=" << x::a << "\n";
    std::cout << "x::y=" << y << "\n";
}
```

---

A outra maneira de simplificar o acesso a variáveis pertencentes a um namespace é utilizando a diretiva "using namespace". Desta maneira **todos** os nomes pertencentes ao namespace podem ser referenciados sem precisar colocar explicitamente o nome do namespace.

O exemplo abaixo ilustra o uso de `using namespace` (note o namespace `z`).

---

```
   #include <iostream>

   int a = 1;

    namespace x
    {
       int a = 2;
       int y = 2;
    };
    using x::y;

    namespace z
    {
      int aa = 1;
      int bb = 2;
    };
    using namespace z;

    int main()
    {
        int b = 3;
        std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << "\n";
        {
           int c = 3;
           std::cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " c=" << c << "\n";
        }

        std::cout << "a=" << a << " x::a=" << x::a << "\n";
        std::cout << "x::y=" << y << "\n";
        std::cout << "z::aa=" << aa << " z::bb=" << bb << "\n";
    }
```

---

Ok, e o que tudo isso tem a ver com `std::cout` ? A resposta é: todas as classes e objetos globais da biblioteca padrão da linguagem C++ estão declarados dentro do namespace `std`.

Assim, para referenciarmos uma classe ou um objeto da biblioteca padrão C++ precisamos especificar que pertencem ao namespace `std`.

Então, podemos utilizar uma das 3 maneiras descritas acima: especificar explicitamente o namespace (como em `std::cout`), ou utilizar uma dretiva para cada nome em `std` (`using std::cout`), ou utilizar uma única diretiva para todos os nomes em `std` (`using namespace std`).

A 3ª maneira, `using namespace std`, não é aconselhada, pois libera o acesso a **todos** os nomes do namespace `std`, dando margem a potenciais conflitos.

Entretanto, é aceitável a utilização de `using namespace std` em pequenos programas, programas exemplo, programas teste, etc, é tudo uma questão de "bom senso".

Para completar, podemos fazer referência explícita a uma variável no namespace global através da notação `::`. Por exemplo, `::a` é uma referência ao nome `a` declarado no namespace global.

(Edit. Faltou ainda falar sobre namespace anônimo, mas isto fica para a próxima.)

Answer (score 11):

`std::cout` é o nome completo do objeto, incluindo o "nome de família" dele, o sobrenome. Muita gente gosta de usar assim, eliminando qualquer ambiguidade.

Outros preferem usar só o nome do objeto para ficar mais curto. É um jeito mais informal de uso. Para ser possível é preciso indicar antes qual família vai usar. A principal do C++ é justamente a `std`. Então fazendo:

```
using namespace std;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/Std.cpp).

dispensa o uso do sobrenome em cada objeto do código que pertença à família `std`.

Veja mais em [Por que não é uma boa prática usarmos namespace "std" em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38435/101) para entender as vantagens e desvantagens dele. Mas na essência é gosto.

[Um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120214/101).