# O que é std em C++?

Tags: c++, namespace

Eu estou aprendendo C++ e vejo `std` sendo usando em todo lugar.

O que é esse `std`? Ele é como se fosse uma biblioteca ou é algo diferente disso?

Comment: É bom dizer que `std` é abreviação de _"standard"_, que significa padrão, padronizado.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ele é um espaço de nomes para os identificadores. Você pode criar os seus, qualquer biblioteca pode ter um ou mais espaços de nomes, que não deixa de ser um identificador que dá um sobrenome para outros nomes. Pode ver mais em [O que é o using namespace?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/348049/101).

No caso do `std` ele é o espaço de nomes padrão da linguagem, então tudo o que é padrão do C++ é colocado com esse sobrenome. Exemplo clássico é o [Diferença entre std::cout e cout?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151604/101).

O *namespace* foi criado em C++ resolvendo alguns problemas de redefinição que existiam em C, por exemplo tem a função `double sin(double)` em `math.h` e ao incluí-lo não se pode definir outro `double sin(double)` sem que dê erro de compilação. Já em C++ tem a biblioteca `cmath` onde o sin vem no namespace `std`, daí pode-se fazer isso e cada um implementado para dar resultado diferentemente dá um resultado diferente:

```
#include <cmath>

namespace myLib {
    double sin( double x ){
        return x*( 1 + x*x*( -1./6 + x*x*(1./120) ) ) ;  
    }
}

double sin(double x) {
    return x * (1 + x * x * (-1. / 6 + x * x * (1. / 120 - x * x * (-1. / 5040))));  
}

main() {
    using namespace myLib;
    double sin3std = std::sin(3.0);
    double sin3myLib = myLib::sin(3.0);
    double sin3 = sin(3.0);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Library/Std.cpp).

É bom ler sobre a polêmica: [Por que não é uma boa prática usarmos namespace "std" em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38435/101).